# ajax post request contentType causes "bad request" error

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

When I add contentType: "application/json" to this ajax post request I get an error in the browser console "bad request"

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: posturl,
  data: {
    authenticity_token: $('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content,
    msg_time: msg_time,
    sender: sender,
    sender_name: sender_name,
    body: msgbody,
  },
  success: function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  },
  error: function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  },
});
```

Comment: How are you adding the contentType? When does the error occur and exactly what does it say? Is the error from the server? What's the server doing and what content is it expecting?

Comment: ```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: posturl,
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: ...
```
strict-origin-when-cross-origin, is that enough information

Comment: How about the other questions? Chiefly, where's the error coming from and what's the server expecting/doing?

Comment: In my rails app a react component is making the ajax post request to a rails controller which in turn will broadcast to a channel and be rendered into a view with the same name as the controller action The controller action creates messages in a mailboxer setup and renders a chat style view

Comment: So is the request reaching the Rails controller? What `params` is it seeing? What's the code for your Rails controller & does it `respond_to :json`?

Comment: It uses a mailboxer method current_user.reply_to_conversation and the ActionCable.server.broadcast so there's no response except that the request has remote true

Comment: So do you think the issue lies in the Rails code (i.e. the info is being sent correctly but processed wrongly)? If so, you've shared the wrong code in the question. What we'd need to see is your Rails controller. As I said, the way to tell is to check what `params` are reaching the controller. Alternatively, how are you rendering the response? Perhaps you're not returning JSON that your React app can use. Again, we need to see the controller (& poss. the view as well).

Comment: Try `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", data : JSON.stringify(data)`. contentType says what you send to the server and that data is not json.

Comment: razvans: contentType: 'text/html' doesn't work either

Comment: razvans: That worked Over in the view I also had to use html_safe otherwise json rendered visible html tags

Answer (score 1):

As razvan said in his comment I needed to use contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",